# Trying to parse 2-d JSON array for the aggregations I want

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, multidimensional-array, aggregation

Basically I want to parse this JSON 2-day array(example of snapshot data below) to sum up all the values for cases and deaths for each date, including the states.  It will ignore the state column and just add up cases and deaths from all state for each date. I can do it in SQL, difficult in javascript.

So in the end it will look like:

the JSON 2-d array that looks like this :

```
{date: "2020-02-17", totalCases: "7", totalDeaths: "1"}
{date: "2020-02-18", totalCases: "150", totalDeaths: "2"}
{date: "2020-02-19",  totalCases: "210", totalDeaths: "3"}
{date: "2020-02-20",  totalCases: "350", totalDeaths: "7"}
```

THE original JSON OBJECT to be aggregated IS BELOW

```
138: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "7", deaths: "0"}
139: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"}
140: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
141: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "10", deaths: "0"}
142: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Texas", fips: "48", cases: "2", deaths: "0"}
143: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Washington", fips: "53", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
144: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Wisconsin", fips: "55", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
145: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Arizona", fips: "04", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
146: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "7", deaths: "0"}
147: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"}
148: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
149: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "10", deaths: "0"}
150: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Texas", fips: "48", cases: "2", deaths: "0"}
151: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Washington", fips: "53", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
152: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Wisconsin", fips: "55", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
153: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Arizona", fips: "04", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
154: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "8", deaths: "0"}
155: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"}
156: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"}
157: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "11", deaths: "0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `reduce`.

```js
const records = {
 138: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "7", deaths: "2"},
 139: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"},
 140: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 141: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "10", deaths: "0"},
 142: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Texas", fips: "48", cases: "2", deaths: "0"},
 143: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Washington", fips: "53", cases: "1", deaths: "2"},
 144: {date: "2020-02-18", state: "Wisconsin", fips: "55", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 145: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Arizona", fips: "04", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 146: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "7", deaths: "0"},
 147: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"},
 148: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 149: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "10", deaths: "0"},
 150: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Texas", fips: "48", cases: "2", deaths: "0"},
 151: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Washington", fips: "53", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 152: {date: "2020-02-19", state: "Wisconsin", fips: "55", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 153: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Arizona", fips: "04", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 154: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "California", fips: "06", cases: "8", deaths: "0"},
 155: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Illinois", fips: "17", cases: "2", deaths: "0"},
 156: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Massachusetts", fips: "25", cases: "1", deaths: "0"},
 157: {date: "2020-02-20", state: "Nebraska", fips: "31", cases: "11", deaths: "0"}
};


const res = Object.values(records).reduce((acc, {date, cases, deaths}) => {
 if (acc[date] !== undefined) {
  acc[date].totalCases += (+cases);
  acc[date].totalDeaths += (+deaths);
 } else {
  acc[date] = {date, totalCases: (+cases), totalDeaths: (+deaths)};
 }

 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: I have a JSON obj array that looks like below.  My code is doing this . But its not working, none of the arrays have values in them, theyre all null.  Im trying to take the values of a JSON obj array and store them in their own array. 

    var nationDays=[];
    var nationCases=[];
 var nationDeaths=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
               
    nationDays.push(i);
    nationCases.push(res[i].totalCases);
    nationDeaths.push(res[i].totalDeaths);
   }

Comment: Is res a JSON obj?  Im trying to retrieve the columns for totalCases, and totalDeaths, and size to store into totalCasesArray totalDeathsAray and DaysArray from size.  I cant parse this res obj though.

Comment: ```Object.values(res).forEach(item => {nationDeaths.push(item.totalDeaths); nationCases.push(item.totalCases)});``` try this.